# How to edit GUI elements on a specific frame in VB6

Tags: vb6, frame, children

**How I can get access to the nested controls of a control?**

I have serveral frames on my user interface and every frame contains serveral other controls (like labels, buttons, ...). I have to iterate over the frames and change content of the children of a specific frame (e.g. set another text in a label).

So far I iterate over all controls of my frame and I check if the control in the loop control variable is the frame where the changes should be.

```
Dim cntrl As Control
For Each cntrl In Controls
  'Debug.Print cntrl.Name  // here I get all controls on the form
  If cntrl.Name = "Frame_Name" Then
    If cntrl.Index = index Then
      Debug.Print "true" ' here the caption of nested components should be changed 
    End If
  End If
Next
```

Now I have the frame in the control variable but the problem is that I get no access to the nested label to change the label's caption. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the Container property of each control.  The following code should give you the idea:

```
Dim cntrl As Control

For Each cntrl In Controls
   If cntrl.Container.Name = "Frame_Name" Then
      Debug.Print cntrl.Name & " is nested in the specified frame"
   End If
Next
```